# Manipulating links in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to create a main main.html file that could alter links inside another second.html file. 
In the second.html i have a player that uses .m3u8 links and i wanted to know if there is any way to modify this link from the main.html page.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific or add some code for context?

Comment: Showing your effort to achieve that will be a good start.

Comment: Sorry guys im new on stackoverflow

Comment: @ElliottRhys I have a .m3u8 player on my second.html file that uses a http://(link)/.m3u8 and i was wondering if is there any way of changing this link from the main.html i wanted to create. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to call your main.html with some sort of form action ("GET", "POST", ...) on your second.html to achieve that. The parameter sent being the URI.

On your main.html you can then dynamically create or alter the markup to include the correct link.

You will probably want to use PHP for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be your are suppose to asking:

I simple put this may be as follows

There is header(menu bar) which is which is in separate HTML file(ex: a.html). Now another HTML file with remaining content(body) is taken in which to include a.html.
If any links in a.html is changed then automatically links in other pages changes because it is included in other files.

As per me it can be done easily by using PHP with:

`include(fileName.fileExtension);`

eg:

`include(filetoInclude.php);`

Another Way is by using Jquery:

```
<div class="file_include"></div>   

 <script type="text/javascript">    
$(function(){
    $(".file_include").load("a.html");
});</script>
```